# Arduino to read file data from SD storage board, and PC user to update same file via usb cable as needed

Tags: arduino, sd, board, storage

I have a project where in the finished product (sketch loaded to Arduino and it's running on its own), Arduino needs to regularly read data from a text file stored on a SPI Micro SD storage board (the ones sold on ebay). The problem is that the same file also needs to be regularly updated by a user by using a PC connected to the system via a USB cable. The user to simply use Windows Explorer to browse and open the same text file stored on the SD card and edit/save it with notepad.
What is the simplest way to accomplish this? What hardware do I need? Is there a SPI Micro SD storage board that also has a slave USB connector (and its interface hardware) to allow access to the file system on the Mirco SD card with PC's Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

> Arduino needs to regularly read data from a text file stored on a SPI Micro SD [...]
>   regularly updated by a user by using a PC connected to the system via a USB

The Micro sd cannot be used by 2 independent systems simultanously. You can either use it from the Arduino or from the PC as USB Mass storage but not both at the same time.

Simplest approach from *hardware* perspective would be a terminal interface (via UART) from the PC (using putty for example) and do all the editing in arduino software, which talks to the SD card via SPI.

Comment: "terminal interface (via UART) from the PC "  Except he stated he wants to use Windows Explorer.